# Error overriding get method in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework. In my work I was suggested to work in an existing project and learn the Rest Framework on the fly. So I was writing an api to display the vehicle-list with both the `get_queryset` method and the `get` method. I could make the `get_queryset()` method work, but the `get()` method isn't working (I'm assuming some kind of syntax error).

The working code :

```
class VehicleList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = FleetVehicleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        domain = self.request.META.get('HTTP_DOMAIN', None)
        if domain is None:
            raise Exception("Domain is missing in request header")
        qs = FleetVehicle.objects.using(domain).all()
        return qs
```

Not working code:

```
class VehicleList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = FleetVehicleSerializer

  def get(self, request):
        domain = self.request.META.get('HTTP_DOMAIN', None)
        if domain is None:
            raise Exception("Domain is missing in request header")
        vehicles = FleetVehicle.objects.using(domain).all()
        return Response({'a': vehicles},status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type = 'application/json' )
```

The output is supposed to be a json, I am testing the api in postman. Can anyone help me with the possible syntax error?

Comment: Probably you need to override `def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` method. Also your 1st implementation looks better than 2nd

Comment: @Exprator I am not familar with stacktrace. What is it and how to get it?

Comment: I mean what error are you getting while calling the API from Postman

Comment: [Here](http://snippi.com/s/6ho1xcb) @Exprator

Comment: what is the url of this view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get(self, request):
        domain = self.request.META.get('HTTP_DOMAIN', None)
        if domain is None:
            raise Exception("Domain is missing in request header")
        vehicles = FleetVehicle.objects.using(domain).all()
        data = FleetVehicleSerializer(vehicles,many=True)
        return Response({'a': data.data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type = 'application/json' )
```

well according to the error you were getting in the `get` method I have given the solution.

Comment: Yes it works. Can you explain what the `data = FleetVehicleSerializer(vehicles,many=True)` is doing? Why I have to say `data.data` in the Response ?

Comment: well DRF cannot send queryset as response, that line actually finds the columns you have mentioned in the serializer and creates a json with `data` as key, so to get the original data, you need to access the key `data` thus `data.data`

Comment: what is the url of this view

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [**`list`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listmodelmixin) method for `ListAPIView`. You can do it like this:

```
class VehicleList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = FleetVehicleSerializer

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        domain = self.request.META.get('HTTP_DOMAIN', None)
        if domain is None:
            raise Exception("Domain is missing in request header")
        vehicles = FleetVehicle.objects.using(domain).all()
        data = self.get_serializer(vehicles, many=True).data
        return Response({'a': data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type = 'application/json' )
```

Comment: I am new so maybe I am not getting it, but from where is this list method is coming? Wasn't I supposed to override the get method?

Comment: @ProteetiProva `ListAPIView` `get` method is just calling `list` method - https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L193-L199

Comment: Generally in django, we override `get()` method for GET requests. But in DRF, when we are using GenericViews, it uses these [mixins](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins). In each mixin, there is a particular method to do separate tasks, like `retrieve` for GET, `update` for PUT etc. This design is to combine multiple mixins and generate views to allow them to do many operations(like doing retrieve, update, list in save class). You can checkout [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35) as well.

Comment: @ProteetiProva regarding the error, in line 39 I see `data = (vehicles, many=True).data` instead of `data = self.get_serializer(vehicles, many=True).data`.

Comment: what is the url of this view